# Assign a reference return value to a non-reference variable

Tags: c++, reference

```
class A { ... };
A& getA();
A anA = getA();
```

What happens exactly on line 3 ?

Is the copy constructor of A called, thus creating an object independent from the one returned (by reference) by the function?

Comment: Yes, just make sure `getA()` doesn't return a local object.

Comment: What's wrong with returning a local object, if a copy is made of it anyway?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Is the copy constructor of A called, thus creating an object independent from the one returned (by reference) by the function?

Yes. The copy constructor takes a reference to the source object as it's parameter and a copy is independent of the original object assuming the copy constructor does a deep copy.

Comment: So the same copy ctor will be called when its a reference variable or a non-reference variable? How does the compiler know to do that